# Destructuring object having hyphen in property name

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to `destructure` an object having a **hyphen** in the property names. I get a `SyntexError` while doing so (which is reasonable because JS doesn't allow variable name with a `hyphen`).

```js
let human= {
    "first-name":"John",
    "last-name":"Doe",
    age:150
}

let {age}= human;
// let {"first-name"}= human;//error
// let {first-name}= human;//error

console.log(age)
```

Comment: how would you like to access the variable later?

Comment: @NinaScholz something like `window["first-name"]`? Not sure though, thats why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alias the property name [using the colon syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

```
let human = {
  "first-name": "John",
  "last-name": "Doe",
  age: 150
};

let { age, "first-name": firstName } = human;
console.log(age, firstName);
```

Comment: I was 98.3% sure that I won't get any answer (or the exact answer I am looking for) but StackOverflow never fails me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the code not working for you is because `first-name` is not a valid variable name in Javascript as it considers that as a minus operator rather than hyphen during `console.log(first-name)`. So, the fix could be to rename the object property to `first_name` and use it elsewhere.

```js
let human= {
    "first-name":"John",
    "last-name":"Doe",
    age:150
}

let {age}= human;
let {'first-name':first_name}= human;

console.log(first_name)
```